# Getting Min and Max dates from available list of dates

Tags: coldfusion

I have dates as a list in the following format:

```
09-2012,10-2012,01-2013
```

What will be the better way to access the minimum and maximum dates from the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not really sure which is faster. Here is my list-only-solution below , or you could convert the list to an array and work with that.

This does the job though:

```
<CFSET dates = "" />
<CFLOOP list="09-2012,10-2012,01-2013" index="date">
    <CFSET dates = listappend(dates,DateFormat(createDate(listlast(date,"-"),listfirst(date,"-"),1), "yyyy-mm-dd")) />
</CFLOOP>
<CFSET dates = listsort(dates,"numeric") />
<CFSET min_date = listfirst(dates) />
<CFSET max_date = listlast(dates) />
```

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend transforming the dates in the list to yyyy-mm-dd.

Then you can just sort the list with ListSort and you will get the first and last date by listfirst and listlast

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Seybsen's answer, only going down the regex path:

```
<cfscript>
var data = "09-2012,10-2012,01-2013";
data = listSort( reReplace( data, '([0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])', '\2-\1', 'all' ), 'numeric', 'asc' );
var minDate = listFirst( data );
var maxDate = listLast( data );
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapted @Seybsen's answer to find the max date from a query without doing a query of queries:

```
<cfset maxCompletedDate = ListLast(ListSort(ValueList(queryName.completedDate), "numeric")) />
```

Thought I would put this out there if anyone else is looking of the same thing but, again, credit @Seybsen.

BTW, the dates in the database where formatted `yyyy-mm-dd H:mm:ss`. Timestamps like `2013-09-15 18:43:17`